# Pass MVC / Razor object to javascript / knockout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

In my view I have the following:

```
 <a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name)))">save</a>
```

I'm trying to pass the `@User.Identity.Name` to the js function but I get "unexpected token".  What's a clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED:

It's still the quotes.  Json.Encode is providing double quotes, so you need to enclose your data-bind in singles:

```
<a data-bind='click: saveAboutMe(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name)))'>save</a>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me - I get js errors "Illegal characters"

Comment: Could you possibly view source/inspect the element and post the outputted HTML rendered to the browser?

Comment: Output is: <a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe('" testuser"')"="">save</a>

Comment: Updated answer -- the `Json.Encode` is providing ", so you need to use ' to avoid premature string termination.

Comment: Notice I'm using a single quote wrapping data-bind rather than double-quote.

Comment: I'm retarded, thank you.  I still get red squigglies though... any idea how those can be fixed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37557/discussion-between-j-torres-and-sb2055)

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case I suggest you create create a property in your class and throw that class from controller to view 
like :-

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
   MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();
   objMyClass.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
   return View(objMyClass);
}

public class MyClass
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and now on the view you can hold the value in hidden field.
Now you are able to access the  value of this hidden field anywhere in your java script.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use @Html.AttributeEncode method:

```
<a data-bind="click: saveAboutMe.bind($data, '@(Html.AttributeEncode(User.Identity.Name))')">save</a>
```